# JRecord - Handling duplicate columns in cobol copybook

Tags: cobol, jrecord

I am using *CopybookInputFormat* on git https://github.com/tmalaska/CopybookInputFormat/ to generate hive table definition from COBOL copybook. My copybook has many Fillers (duplicate columns)
but it looks like JRecord is not handling duplicate column name correctly. 
For below copybook, when I iterate columns, JRecord only prints second Filler and ignores first filler.

```
  05 Birth-day              PIC X(002)
  05 Filler                 PIC X(008)
  05 Birth-Month            PIC X(002)
  05 Filler                 PIC X(008)
  05 Birth-year             PIC X(004)
```

Does anyone have any solution for this? I know *JRecord 0.80.6* onward is handling duplicate columns, but method `getUniqueField("FIRST-NAME", "PRESIDENT")` needs a group name.. but what if group has duplicate columns?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should not need to import a **Filler**. In Cobol, a **Filler** can not be directly accessed. In Cobol a **Filler** say's **Ignore** this **Field** (or access it by another method).

A Cobol-Copybook is like a mask over a block of memory; A filler is used to skip some memory.

```
  Data         !##........##........##   (# - accessible bytes; . - inaccessible bytes)
                ^         ^         ^                               
                !         !         !
Birth-day    ---+         !         ! 
Filler                    !         ! 
Birth-Month  -------------+         !  
Filler                              !
Birth-year   -----------------------+
```

A filler can be used to:

- Mask fields that are no longer used.
- Used mask data in a redefines
- Create a simplified version of a copybook when you do not need all the fields
- Initializing an output field i.e

```
     05 report-Birth-date
        10 dd          pic 99.
        10 filler      pic '/'.
        10 mm          pic 99.  
        10 filler      pic '/'.
        10 yyyy        pic 9999.
```

- setting up Table data

```
     05 codes.
        10 code occurs 5  pic 99.
     05 filler redefines codes pic x(10)
        value '0204050612'.
```

---

I would ask the **Cobol specialists** where you *work* **what is going on** ???. Possible answers could be:

- The filler data may not be needed.
- You should be using a different more complicated Copybook.
- The copybook should be updated with the Fillers given real names.